# Incorrect reflections (topology problems) in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, topology

Is it possible to fix these "cracks" that appear when rendering in "Cycles"?

[image][image]

Everything looks correct in EEVEE.

[image]

Maybe the problem is how I modified the "crystal".

[image]

[image]
(Blender v 3.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you *Apply* geometry nodes, you can see hexagons are not flat. They are triangulated. Eevee seems to use different normal info (I'm not so techy, so I'm not sure it is calculated).
Hexagons are not flat because of your *Transform Geometry* node, that scales vertices on Y axis. This kind of math just can't result with real flat faces.
I wanted to move *Dual Mesh* after transformation nodes, but result was similar.*

---

You can use just a **Set Shade Smooth** node and do selection for smoothing by *Face is Planar* node to specify co-planar faces, adjust *Threshold* value ...

[image]
[image]

... or you can limit **Split Edges** node to specify *Edge Angle* (I haven't used this node before so I can be wrong, but it solved the issue).

[image]

Comment: is it possible to specify each mesh face in the "selection" boolean input of the "shade smooth" node to prevent the "split edges" node from being used?

Comment: Yes it is ... edited.